# If $A^3$ diagonalizable, then $A$ diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, diagonalization

I can prove this statement wrong by considering $A\neq\mathbf O$ and $A$ not diagonalizable while $A^3=\mathbf O$.

But what's wrong with my intuitive proof:

$A^3=PDP^{-1}$, and we just consider $A=PD^{1/3}P^{-1}$, it seems that everything is satisfied. And furthermore, we can also show uniqueness by considering in certain eigenspace $V_\lambda$, $A^3=\lambda I$ so the eigenvalue of $A$ must be $\sqrt[3]\lambda$.

Could anyone help me to figure out what's wrong here? And why does the converse hold?

Comment: $(PDP^{-1})^{1/3}\neq PD^{1/3}P^{-1}$.

Comment: Another counterexample (over $\mathbb{R}$) is if $A$ is a rotation by a third of a turn: $A$ has no real eigenvectors, but $A^3 = I$ and so every vector is an eigenvector for $A^3$.

Comment: You postulate that $A = P D^{1/3} P^{-1}$ but you don't prove it. $A$ is given, you cannot choose it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more why $(PDP^{-1}\neq PD^{1/3}P^{-1})$? Because $\sqrt A=PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$

Comment: How would you define $D^{1/3}$ in the complex plane where every complex has 3 cubic roots?

Comment: @Gribouillis, sorry i just started to learn complex part of linear algebra. Could you explain more about "3 cubic roots"? My intuition is that for every given $\lambda$, $\sqrt[3]\lambda$ is unique

Comment: @Jerry for example $(-\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^3 = (\exp(i 2\pi/3))^3 = 1$. See 'Root of unity' on wikipedia.

Comment: @Gribouillis, so my proof is wrong here is because $D^{1/3}$ is not unique when we allow complexification?

Comment: @Gribouillis, but what if we only focus on real number? It seems that this statement is also false

Comment: Your proof is wrong because you don't prove that $A = P D^{1/3}P^{-1}$, whichever way you define $D^{1/3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the problem in the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers.

If $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$, the result is false in general as the following example shows
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\cr 0&0&1\cr 0&0&0\cr\end{pmatrix}
\qquad A^3=0
\end{equation}

If $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^3$, the result is true by the following argument: assuming $A^3$ is diagonalizable, let
$P(X) = \prod_i (X-\mu_i)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A^3$, with $\mu_i\not = \mu_j$ for $i\not = j$, and let $Q(x)=\prod (X-\lambda_i)^{m_i}$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. Obviously,
\begin{equation}
R(X) = P(X^3) = \prod_i (X^3-\mu_i)
\end{equation}
is a multiple of $Q(X)$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ because $R(A)=0$. It follows that if $\lambda$ is a root of $Q$, then $R(\lambda) = 0$ and one has $\lambda^3 = \mu_k$ for some index $k$. In particular one has $\lambda\not = 0$. If $\lambda$ is a multiple root of $Q$, then it must also be a multiple root of $R$. But one has
\begin{equation}
R'(\lambda) = \sum_i 3 \lambda^2 \prod_{j\not = i} (\lambda^3-\mu_j) =
3 \lambda^2 \prod_{j\not = k} (\mu_k-\mu_j) \not = 0
\end{equation}
Thus $\lambda$ cannot be a multiple root of $R$, hence $Q$ has only simple roots and $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3):

> we can also show uniqueness

We cannot, because given a matrix $B$, there may be several matrices such that $A^3=B$. So you finding the one which is diagonalizable simultaneously with $B$ does not mean much.